# STS not detecting AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services

I set up my AWS Eclipse Toolkit account as mentioned in this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-eclipse/v1/user-guide/setup-install.html#prerequisites) and have also been writing Lambda functions without any issues for a while now.
However when trying to test the SNS Mobile Push sample app, I could not find the AWS SDK in the Java Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries settings. 
I even tried to re install the AWS Toolkit (including setting credentials) but no impact. 
Please help me understand what could I be missing ?
[My Project Configure Build Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9Uwm.png)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could resolve this was to download the aws sdk & include the aws-java-sdk-x.xx.xx.jar (inside lib folder), into the project build path. 
Somehow could not get AWS SDK to get automatically detected in the Libraries section after setting up the AWS Tooklit in STS.